# How to find specific actor in Akka

Tags: java, akka, actor

In java

I have simple web application. In `ServletContextListener` I create actor

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
actor = system.actorOf(new Props(MyServerActor.class), "MyServer");
actor.tell(new StartMessage());
```

this actor has path `akka://MySystem/user/MyServer`. Then I try to send message to this actor from business method

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
client = system.actorSelection("/user/MyServer"); // same effect when use actorFor
client.tell("OK");
```

`onReceive` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message + " :  " + message);
}
```

but my actor doesn’t receive message. It look like i send it to /dev/null.

Where is mistake?

//edit:

I try to use fullpath too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'm so stupid...

I create two `System` so the cannot access one to another, cannot find actor so message were send to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

you can try with remote actors:

```
String path = "akka://MySystem@some-ip:some-port/some/sub/path"
ActorRef xxx = actorSystem.actorFor(path);
```

Also, it would be better if you have subscribe the deadLetters() actor to record the unhandled messages.

```
final ActorRef actor = actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(DefaultDeadLetterHandlerActor.class));
actorSystem.eventStream().subscribe(actor, DeadLetter.class);
```

by maybe just simply log them.